# How to print in the first input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When i run this code.

```
number = int(input())
collect = [] #collect number from input
for i in range(number):
  x = int(input())
  collect.append(x)
print(collect)
for j in [ele for ind, ele in enumerate(collect,1) if ele not in collect[ind:]]:
    count = 0
    for ele in collect:
        if j == el:
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
    if count != 0:
        print("{} : {} Items".format(ind, count))
    else:
        print("{} : {} Item".format(j, count))
```

```
**input:**  5
             2
             1
             2
             1
             2 

**output:** 


5

2
1
2
1
2

[2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

1 : 2 Items

2 : 3 Items
```

> I would like to show

**output:**

```
5

2
1
2
1
2

[2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

2 : 3 Items
1 : 2 Items
```

> How to do it

Comment: if j == el:. What is el here?

Comment: Print each element inside the first `for` loop

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about printing "in" inputs. What is *different* about what is actually printed, vs. what you want to print?

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input())
print()
collect = [] #collect number from input
for i in range(number):
  x = int(input("\n"))
  collect.append(x)
print("\n\n" + str(collect))
y = [ele for ind, ele in enumerate(collect,1) if ele not in collect[ind:]]
y.reverse()
for j in y:
    count = 0
    for ele in collect:
        if j == el:
            count += 1
        else:
            pass
    if count != 0:
        print("\n{} : {} Items".format(ind, count))
    else:
        print("\n{} : {} Item".format(j, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
number = int(input())
collect = [] #collect number from input
for i in range(number):
  x = int(input())
  collect.append(x)
print(collect)

from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(collect)
for a,b in sorted([v,k for k,v in counter.items()], reverse=True) :
    print("{} : {} Item{}".format(b, a, 's' if a != 1 else ''))
```